# Отрисовка больших графов

Tags: веб-программирование, графы

Есть интересная задача по отрисовке больших неориентированных графов (более 10 тысяч нод) в веб приложении. Помимо отрисовки необходимо также показывать распространение некого контента по этой сети, т.е. линки и ноды меняют свой цвет по некоторому алгоритму (распространение запускается вручную юзером после отрисовки топологии графа). Посоветуйте пожалуйста, что использовать, в какую сторону смотреть. Хотелось бы рассмотреть разные варианты с соответствующими преимуществами и недостатками, заранее спасибо.

Comment: смотрели d3 -- d3js.org - https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery?

Comment: Примеры достаточно интересны, но важен вопрос в рекомендуемых технологиях, есть ли смысл смотреть в строну flash, java fx и тп? или подобные большие вычисления (графы предполагаются достаточно большими) лучше реализовать на стороне клиента средствами html и  js библиотек. если смотреть на отрисовку силами js, какие библиотеки нужно рассматривать в качестве приоритета?

Comment: _"есть ли смысл смотреть в строну flash, java fx и тп?"_ -- с flash переходят на html5, про java fx и т.д. не знаю. _"если смотреть на отрисовку силами js"_ -- см. http://processingjs.org/

Comment: Спасибо, не подскажите ещё какие нибудь подобные библиотеки?, хотелось бы выбирать из чего-то. Возможно есть информация о недостатках тех или иных js api и т.д. или какие-нибудь ещё варианты визуализации больших графов.

Comment: _"ещё какие нибудь подобные библиотеки?"_ -- список [тут](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing.js#See_also) и [тут](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D3.js#Similar_tools_and_libraries)